# Use bluetooth music system to play sound of phone calls

Tags: calls, bluetooth-audio

I have an Xiaomi Pocophone F1 with Android 9. Its currently unrooted but I would not hesitate to root it, if considered neccessary.

I have music systems capable to play music over bluetooth. Think of bluetooth headphones (without microphones!) for example. Unsurprisingly, they provide a much better sound quality than my phone's loudspeakers.

When I make/receive phone calls, I would like to play the sound using these music systems but still speak into the phone's microphone. Could anyone please hint me how this can be achieved.

Comment: Mayve an app like [SoundAbout](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.woodslink.android.wiredheadphoneroutingfix) can do that (this app tells the system where to route which audio to).

Comment: I saw that mentioned in some german forum too (https://www.android-hilfe.de/forum/android-allgemein.20/telefon-audio-ueber-bluetooth-schicken.790408.html). Unfortunately, seems to be abandoned; the recent version is from 2016 and does not start on my device.

Comment: I didn't encounter any replacement yet. I know there was no update since 2016 – but I didn't know it won't even start on Pie, sorry.